# Is Firebug on Firefox 3 stable yet?

Tags: firebug, firefox-3

I really should upgrade to Firefox 3, but I'm very dependent on Firebug working properly.

I know there is a version of Firebug that is supposed to work with Firefox 3, but last time I looked, there seemed to be problems with it.

So, for those that have made the jump, is Firebug on Firefox 3 ready for prime time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I've been using Firebug heavily and it's been rock-steady. What problems were you having in particular? We could test and report the results.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is stable on Firefox 3, but you have to upgrade to version 1.2.1, since previous version no longer work.

For some reason, I had to do this update manually: uninstalling the previous version and installing the new one.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using FF3 with Firebug 1.2.1 for a while now and not encountered any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "jump" to FF3.  Install it alongside Firefox 2 and try it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The network monitoring still breaks HTTP headers, and consequently caching.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Firefox now its very user friendly and ease of use but the thing is its consuming more memory

Answer (score 1):

Firebug 1.2.x (the only version that works with Firefox 3) no longer appears to have the option to disable Firebug for only certain webpages and sites.  If you use this feature you may prefer to stay with FF 2.

Comment: You can enable/disable Console, Script, Network and Cookies (if you have Firecookies) per site or globally, per tab (v.1.2.1 - drop down arrow in the tabs). I find it is a good improvement, since these are the resource consuming features.

Answer (score 1):

Not only it works fine, but it has great improvements over the FF2 version, like allowing to disable Console, Script, Network and Cookies (if you have Firecookies) to use less resources (a big problem in FF2 if you don't have much memory and have lot of tabs), and allowing/disallowing them per site. Among other improvements...

Answer (score 1):

When doing "console.log" calls on jQuery objects, in Firefox 3 you get "Object" and you have to expand them to see what are they. In Firefox 2 you get a nice list with the names linked to the DOM nodes that is so much easier to see.

As far as I've seen, when you monitor XHR calls in Firebug on Firefox 3, you have to click a button to see the server response of POST calls. The Firebug people say this is a workaround for a bug in Firefox 3 and last time I checked they were still waiting for it to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there's a bug in firebug 1.3.3 on firefox 3.0.9 that causes it not to send an If-modified-since header so it always gets a copy from the server instead of using the cached local copy.

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1274&q=etag&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary